# Connecting to Firebird 3

Tags: database-connection, firebird, firebird-3.0, flamerobin

I have installed Firebird 3.0.1 on a PC and on a VM client. I installed Flamerobin on both to test the connection.

1. I can connect to localhost on both PC and VM using Flamerobin, so I assume the Firebird server is running on both and Flamerobin is installed on both OK
2. I can connect to the Firebird server on the VM from the PC and open a database Ok
3. From the VM I can open a database on the PC, but when I try to retrieve the server version on the PC I get an error `ISC_Service_attach failed (Unable to complete network request to host)`.

I have no idea what the problem is given that I can open a database ok, but cannot access any of the utility services.

I am using fbclient.dll 3.0.1.32591 on both VM and PC

Comment: BTW the PC is Win10 64 bit and the VM is Win7 32 bit. (FB and Flamerobin are both 32 bit in my test setup)
Could someone confirm that they can retrieve the server version from a PC connecting to FB3 running on Win10

Comment: Have you tried with Firebird 3.0.2?

Comment: Note that this may be a question that is better asked on the Firebird-support mailinglist, as that is a better venue for troubleshooting problems that don't have a clear answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you can achieve network request to server, you need to check firewall setings on server and set fb default port as inbound acceptable. If you would had same problem after that, than you probably need proper fbclient library, for FB3 on client, VM. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Boki - it was the firewall (allowed port 3050 to fix). I was confused that I could open a database without the rule but not backup...)

Comment: @Tony this "I could open a database without the rule but not backup" is very weird. Perhaps you did connected to some different database, perhaps you could do some SELECTs from Monitoring Tables, to check which database and which connection(attachment) features were used. You did not show connection strings, but obviously for firewall there is no difference between mere connecting to the server and connecting to the server and then attaching a DB. There should be some other factor we miss here

Comment: @Arioch'The It totally confused me (easy to do). Without the rule flamerobin could not connect but my trivial Delphi app could open a database using the TIBDatabase component (it builds the connection string internally I think). I do not know enough about FB - maybe it runs different services for different tasks.

Comment: "using the TIBDatabase component" IBExpress is designed to work with Interbase not with Firebird. How much they still are compatible is an open question. For example IBX uses GDS32.dll not fbclient.dll / No, Firebird uses only one service, but you may have several Firebird instances (example: different versions) installed and running. Also there is embedded server, which is not a process but a DLL for the program like SQLite. And while in FB2 it was a separate build, in FB3 it is a default mode for local connections.

Comment: Check via monitoring tables your server, DB and connection properties. Something like  c:\Program Files\Firebird\Firebird_2_1\doc\README.monitoring_tables.txt

Comment: @Tony you are welcome. I am glad I was able to help.

Comment: @Tony The only guess I can make is that your application connects using the Firebird XNET protocol, and not the 'normal' TCP/IP protocol.